# How to input values automatically in arrays (C++)?

Tags: c++, arrays

so I'm stuck on this little thing that has been causing lots of problems for me. Let's say I have interval of 2 numbers `[x,y]`. I manually input the values of x and y. The thing is I want to make an array ranging from x to y. For example if `x = 1` and `y = 5`, array would be `[1,2,3,4,5]`.
Here's the code that is supposed to do what I just described:

```
` for (t=0;t<y;t++){
  for (x=x;x<y;x++){
   q[t] == x;
   cout <<q[t];
  }
}`
```

Instead it out prints `4259904`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `q[t] == x;` is a NOP. Did you mean `q[t] = x;`?

Answer (score 0):

Hey try out the following code :

```
cin>>x;
cin>>y;
int a;
if(x>y)
{
  numberofelements=x-y+1;
  a=y;
}
else
{
numberofelements=y-x+1;
a=x;
}
int array1[numberofelements];
for(int i=0;i<numberofelements;i++,a++)
 array1[i]=a;
```

let me know if it works

Comment: That `int array1[numberofelements];` line is a big no-no in C++. Read on *variable-length arrays*.

Comment: while answering i was looking mainly at the for loops cause nested for loops really didnt make much sense